# Why does this MySQL query work in phpmyadmin but doesn't return anything in my php script?

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin, left-join, temp-tables

I have tried the following query in phpmyadmin and it returns the correct results, but when I try passing the result to a variable in php that variable is essentially empty (i.e., when I try using it in a while loop with mysql_fetch_array, I get nothing. And mysql_num_rows returns only 1).

Could this be tied to the fact that I'm creating a temporary table in MySQL? Here's the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE solved
SELECT comments.nid FROM flag_content
LEFT JOIN comments ON flag_content.content_id=comments.cid
LEFT JOIN term_node ON term_node.nid=comments.nid
WHERE flag_content.fid=3 AND term_node.tid=522;

SELECT node.nid, node.title, users.name, node_counter.totalcount, node_comment_statistics.comment_count, node_comment_statistics.last_comment_timestamp
FROM node
LEFT JOIN term_node ON node.nid = term_node.nid
LEFT JOIN node_comment_statistics ON node.nid = node_comment_statistics.nid
LEFT JOIN node_counter ON node.nid = node_counter.nid
LEFT JOIN users ON node.uid = users.uid
LEFT JOIN solved ON node.nid=solved.nid
WHERE term_node.tid=522 AND solved.nid IS NULL;
```

I have this query stored in a PHP function:

```
function getPosts(){
   dbConnect(); //establishes connection
   //"....." in the following line is the above query
   return mysql_query(".......") or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.\n<br />Query: " . $query . "<br />\nError: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error()); 
}
```

And the line of code that calls it is:

```
$result = getPosts();
```

When I call getPosts(), the query dies with a fatal error. I get two versions of the same error depending on whether the query is concatenated across multiple lines with "." or simply written on a single line.

Error when concatenated across multiple lines:

```
Error: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comments.nid FROM flag_content LEFT JOIN comments ON flag_content.content_id=com' at line 1
```

Error when written on a single line:

```
Error: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT node.nid, node.title, users.name, node_counter.totalcount, node_comment_s' at line 1
```

Comment: need to see the php, that clearly seems to be the part at issue

Comment: a little error checking may be all you need:

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.\n<br />Query: " . $query . "<br />\nError: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());

Comment: @Dagon - I've edit the post to show the PHP. Pretty basic. As I said in the post, echo mysql_num_rows($result) just gives me the number 1, while it should have about 15 rows. I'll try the error checking you suggested first thing in the morning.

Comment: there are no database connection credentials inside the function, that could be the issue, the above code will give you the exact mysql error.

Comment: When you run the query in phpmyadmin, do you have the query outputting back to your screen?  I've noticed that sometimes phpmyadmin will parse and re-piece a query back together with a some editing.  It's possible it's detecting something minor and adjusting for you.

Comment: @Dagon - I do have connection credentials inside the function. I just failed to show that in my post. I've edited it accordingly. Sorry about that, I know posting mistakes like these just waste peoples' time.

Comment: @jerebear - Yes, it's outputting back on the screen, and I get the results I want. The output looks pretty standard; I don't see anything that would suggest that it's doing any editing.

Comment: @Dagon - I updated my code to include the die() error checking. It does indeed produce an error, although I don't know why. I've edited my above post to include the output of this error.

Comment: @maxedison it's because you are trying to run 2 queries at once, while in phpmyadmin you can, separating them with a semicolon, you can't via php -mysql_query()

Comment: @Dagon I learn something new every day. Jeremy provided me with the actual code below. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try executing the queries one at a time. create the temp table, select into it, then drop it as three separate queries. as a security precaution, the sql socket only allows one query in an execution block

It would look something like...

```
mysql_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE solved
SELECT comments.nid FROM flag_content
LEFT JOIN comments ON flag_content.content_id=comments.cid
LEFT JOIN term_node ON term_node.nid=comments.nid
WHERE flag_content.fid=3 AND term_node.tid=522;");
```

$result = mysql_query("SELECT node.nid, node.title, users.name, node_counter.totalcount, node_comment_statistics.comment_count, node_comment_statistics.last_comment_timestamp
FROM node
LEFT JOIN term_node ON node.nid = term_node.nid
LEFT JOIN node_comment_statistics ON node.nid = node_comment_statistics.nid
LEFT JOIN node_counter ON node.nid = node_counter.nid
LEFT JOIN users ON node.uid = users.uid
LEFT JOIN solved ON node.nid=solved.nid
WHERE term_node.tid=522 AND solved.nid IS NULL;
");

Comment: Would you mind giving my an example? I'm not very experienced with MySQL.